# Customizing error state for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working with 4.0+ EditText and have to perform validations on a bunch of fields. When a validation fails, I have to change the color of the EditText to red and display a message. Now, I have easily customized the EditText using style and theme, but there is no state for error which I can use in the state list drawable. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using [LevelListDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`EditText.setError(CharSequence error)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

The result will look like this

[image: validation failed]

Comment: I want to use that, but want to display the error in the way I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You want to change to red background color or text color?

Comment: I want to change the line color

Comment: What line color? EditText's border line?

Comment: Than you have to implement your own class extending EditText, and override `setError()`.